# Why am I getting an error that addr is not configured for ENS when trying to transfer an ERC20 token on Goerli testnet?

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js, testnets, react, ens

So I am getting this: `Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name (argument="name", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)`

I know everything's well configured, I triple checked, the contract's has been deployed on Goerli testnet, however, what am I missing? Help appreciated. Here is my react app:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const contractAddress = "0x4193f089C9e41135329c989a0899B60B101C3994"
const USDCAddress = "0x07865c6E87B9F70255377e024ace6630C1Eaa37F"

const ERC20ABI = ["function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance)"]

const ABI = [
  "function safeTransfer(IERC20 _token, address _seller, uint256 _amount) external payable",
  "event Transfer(address buyerAddress, address sellerAddress, uint depositAmount, uint256 counter)"
];

function App() {

const [amount, setDepositValue] = useState('')
const [_seller, setSellerAddress] = useState('')

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
const signer = provider.getSigner()

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, signer);

async function isConnected() {
  const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_accounts'});       
  if (accounts.length) {
     console.log(`You're connected to: ${accounts[0]}`);
  } else {
     console.log("Metamask is not connected");
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  async function connectWallet() {
  await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
  }
  connectWallet()
    .catch(console.error)
  isConnected()
})


function handleDepositChange(e) {
  setDepositValue(e.target.value);
}

function handleAddressChange(e) {
  setSellerAddress(e.target.value);
}
const providerContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, provider);

const depositMade = async () => {

  provider.once("block", () => {
  providerContract.on("Transfer", (buyerAddress, sellerAddress, depositAmount, counter, event) => {

  console.log(
  "Buyer address: "+buyerAddress,
  "Seller address: "+sellerAddress,
  "Escrow amount: "+JSON.stringify(depositAmount.toString()),
  "Escrow ID: "+counter, 
  "Transaction hash: "+event.transactionHash)
})
})
}


function blockchainTalk(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (contract.safeTransfer(USDCAddress, _seller, amount)) {
  depositMade();
}
  
}
return (
          <div className="col">
            <form onSubmit={blockchainTalk}>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="Value to deposit" step="any" defaultValue={101} onChange={handleDepositChange} />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Seller address" defaultValue={"0xF025B4AC25D5DC1FfD77B099a31ddc269D55c039"} onChange={handleAddressChange} />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Transfer</button>
)
}
```

And this is my smart contract function:

```
  function safeTransfer(IERC20 _token, address _seller, uint256 _amount) external payable {
    //need to be checked against re-entrancy attack

    require(_amount > 100, "Escrow value must be above 100 USDC.");

    require(address(_token) == 0x07865c6E87B9F70255377e024ace6630C1Eaa37F, 
    "You can only transfer USDC to the escrow");

    require(token.balanceOf(_seller) >= _amount, 
    "You should have at least the same amount of USDC in your wallet as the amount you want to escrow.");

    Deposit storage _deposit = ids[counter];

    counter++; 

    _deposit.buyer = msg.sender;
    
    _deposit.seller = _seller; 

    token = _token;

    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _seller, _amount, counter);
}
```

Please help me figure this out, am I silly or what?

Answer (score 0):

Reviewning it, `safeTransfer()`shouldn't be payble.

Comment: It returns nothing because you put in /token/ instead of /address/, try this: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x4193f089C9e41135329c989a0899B60B101C3994
Also I did post the human readable ABI of the contract function in the OP: ```const ABI = [
  "function safeTransfer(IERC20 _token, address _seller, uint256 _amount) external payable",
  "event Transfer(address buyerAddress, address sellerAddress, uint depositAmount, uint256 counter)"
];```